# Parse XML list to typed object using annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this xml that return of a web service:

```
<return>
<LuckNumber>
    <Number>00092</Number>
    <CodError>00</CodError>
    <Serie>019</Serie>
    <Number>00093</Number>
    <CodError>00</CodError>
    <Serie>019</Serie>
    <Number>00094</Number>
    <CodError>00</CodError>
    <Serie>019</Serie>
    <Number>00095</Number>
    <CodError>00</CodError>
    <Serie>019</Serie>
</LuckNumber>
```

How Can I parse this XML to a typed object using annotations?

I Tried it, but doesn't work:

```
protected T ProccessResult<T>(string result) {
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(result))
    {
        var resultDeserialize = (T)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));

        return resultDeserialize;
    }
}
```

```
ProccessResult<List<GenerateNumberList>>(STRING_XML_ABOVE)
```

CLASS TO PARSE:

```
[XmlRoot("LuckNumber")]
public class GenerateNumberResult
{
    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public string LuckNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CodError")]
    public string CodError{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Serie")]
    public string Serie { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You should consider changing your XML structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your XML is the "return" element. Add a wrapper class that contains your list:

```
[XmlRoot("return")]
public class ResultWrapper
{
    [XmlElement("LuckNumber")] 
    public List<GenerateNumberResult> numberList;
}
```

And get the result:

```
ResultWrapper result = ProccessResult<ResultWrapper>(xml);
```